# Can we keep reputation earned from edits regardless?

Tags: feature-request, edits, reputation

So recently I was doing a lot of editing to get some reputation, but I noticed that only half of the edits I made actually gave me 2 reputation. The rest of the edits belonged to questions that were deleted. And this is a problem.

It is very frustrating when you check on SO the next day and you seems to lose 10 reputations since the edits you made are now from deleted questions. So can this be fixed? Or is there a very good reason to why this is the way it is?

Comment: Don't waste your time on bad questions and concentrate on good/mediocre questions instead.

Comment: It is only frustrating because you're at a stage where 10 rep can mean the difference between having privileges and not having them. The only way out of that frustration is to do whatever you can to care less about having reputation points, because they will drop from time to time. It is inevitable.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Reputation is awarded for content that is visible on the site. It is expected and somewhat desired<sup>1</sup> to not get reputation for content that is not publicly present on the site - deleted posts, rejected edits, drafts. So far I don't see any reason to change that.

You should look at reputation *as the computed value of visible contributions* and not payment for actions you've performed on the site.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Not getting reputation for deleted posts may encourage people motivated by reputation to focus editing efforts on posts that are likely to stay, rather than contributions that add no value and no one cares about.</sub>